# Display image from URL in Android Recyclerview Imageview with Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am trying to display images from url addresses in a RecyclerView ImageView, But only [this url][1] and [this url][2] image is being displayed. When I change url to other image urls, no images is diplaying, but only white background in the shape of the image comes out.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryGridAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final CategoryGridModel categoryGridModel = categoryGridModels.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(categoryGridModel.getDescription ());
    holder.frameLayout.setBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor (categoryGridModel.getColor ()));
    Glide.with(holder.imageView)
            //.load("https://www.sarahmcculloch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/flat-duolingo.png") //Image not showing with this URL
            .load("https://lh6.ggpht.com/9SZhHdv4URtBzRmXpnWxZcYhkgTQurFuuQ8OR7WZ3R7fyTmha77dYkVvcuqMu3DLvMQ=w300") //Image showing properly
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_icon_volleyball))
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, categoryGridModel.getImageUrl (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What other image Urls you are using ?

Comment: For Example https://www.sarahmcculloch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/flat-duolingo.png

Comment: Thats not a URL you need to append `Http` before it ..

Comment: @ADM, I have edited the code. Please check

Comment: try with some high resolution image . because url you have posted have image of only 256 Pixels

Comment: Glide need a context try `Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext())` not `Glide.with(holder.imageView)`